# Delete comments in a String?

Tags: regex, groovy, removeall

I want to remove simple // comments in a string.
My String is called input

```
def input = '''test //kommentar
              |
              |//noch einer
              |
              |und      noch //einer'''.stripMargin()
```

The regex is `\s*\/\/.*$` and can be tested here http://regexr.com?37ks0

In my code i have `input = input.replaceAll(/\s*\/\/.*$/ , '')`

But it doesn't work. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you need to make sure that the `$` anchor is allowed to match the end of each line, not just the end of the entire string:

```
input = input.replaceAll(/(?m)\s*\/\/.*$/ , '')
```

But what if `//` occur, say, in a quoted string? Or in any other circumstance where they do not mean "start of comment"?

Comment: The answer is `(?m)`. Your example wouldn't work as it stands however, as it won't work with `"`, you need: `'(?m)\\s*//.*$'` or `/(?m)\s*\/\/.*$/` as your pattern.

Comment: @tim_yates: I thought this was about Groovy? Does it employ a regex syntax different from Java?

Comment: It is, and it does.  Your answer is correct as I see it apart from the double quotes will make Groovy try and expand the unescaped `$`.  Not sure where PHP comes into it?

Comment: @tim_yates: I see. Just looked at the Groovy regex documentation. Thanks! And thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to keep the `//noch einer` line as a blank line in your output, you could try:

```
input.replaceAll( '(?m)//.*$' , '' )
```

Of course if the line above was in your input text, then all of this regex munging would break the input code, as that line would become `input.replaceAll('(?m)`

As a general rule, this sort of regular expression parsing of code is never a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the answer from a college.

If it was one line, the code in the description works.
Because I have multilines, I have to use the following:

`input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.compile(/\s*\/\/.*$/, Pattern.MULTILINE), '')`